# sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities fails to provide used columns list when joining with temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, tempdb, temporary-tables, metadata

I think I need some help as I run out of ideas.

In my database I have a simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Invoices 
( 
        CashDiscounts MONEY, 
        Cost MONEY 
) 
GO
```

and a stored procedure that uses this table in SELECT context:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Reporting.pLoadTest 
AS 
BEGIN 
        CREATE TABLE #t ( Test INT ); 

        SELECT  
                  Invoice.[CashDiscounts]       AS [CashDiscounts] 
                , Invoice.[Cost]                        AS [Cost] 
        FROM dbo.Invoices AS Invoice 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #t -- if you remove this join, dm_sql_referenced_entities should return also CashDiscounts and Cost attributes
        ON 1=1 

END 
GO
```

Now, the problem I got is following: I am using system function **sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities** to get list of columns used by *Reporting.pLoadTest.*

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('Reporting.pLoadTest', 'OBJECT')
```

I expect the results of this function to be:

1. dbo.Invoices
2. dbo.Invoices.CashDiscounts
3. dbo.Invoices.Cost

However, when I do a join to temp #t table function **sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities** returns only

1. dbo.Invoices

Everything in this case works fine if I use table variable instead of temp table. I tried to fiddle with permissions for tempdb as written in documentation

> Requires SELECT permission on sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities and VIEW
>   DEFINITION permission on the referencing entity.

but with no positive result.

What should I do to get correct results of columns being used by a stored procedure that do a select and a join to temp table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in SQL Server and here is a Connect item to vote for if you want a change.

[dm_sql_referenced_entities does not shows columnes when temporary tables are used in statement](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/489390/dm-sql-referenced-entities-does-not-shows-columnes-when-temporary-tables-are-used-in-statement)

Current status:

> We believe it is unlikely that we will address this suggestion, and so
>   we are closing it as “won’t fix”.

Comment: Microsoft connect seems to be retired now. Did they move this item to somewhere else?

Comment: @JensWagemaker it is in the documentation now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. `Dependency information is not created or maintained for rules, defaults, temporary tables, temporary stored procedures, or system objects.`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. Just before I posted a question here I did a search Microsoft Connect bug list however nothing came up here and I used dm_sql_referenced_entities as keyword. I've posted the same bug and that's available at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1859356.

Let's say I understand Microsoft policy about that. I wonder however if there is a way to modify and maybe fix sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities function at least on my local instance of SQL Server?